# Rails add one or more relations for a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my ruby on rails application i've two tables: one for the articles and one for the categories.

i create a association with a migration where i set a reference between the articles and the category table:

```
class AddCategoryToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :articles, :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

then i set described the associations in the models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :category
end
```

and

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :articles
end
```

during the registration of one article i want set a table that display all the categories i've create with a checkbox in every line:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| ID | Category     | Select          |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| 1  | Category 1   |      checkbox() | 
| 2  | Category 2   |      checkbox() |
| 3  | Category 3   |      checkbox() |
| 4  | Category 4   |      checkbox() |
```

if i've selected 2 or more category for an article how can i save it?

thanks for all the help

Comment: I have a feeling that this article is exactly what you're looking for: http://millarian.com/rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/

Comment: wow yhea i will tryout this article =) ty dude and i will answer my own question. Ty dude =)